# check if there are 2 instances running

Tags: android

I am trying to check if my app is running already if the user is trying to enter it again.
it is possible if one app Launched   anther one and the user entering with a mobile to the second one, and will be 2 instance.

my launcher app that starts the original one  looks like that :

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();

  i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.test.vayo");
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   startActivity(i);
```

On my original code I am trying to check if there is 2 instance but always get true on this code

```
    if (processName == null) {
        return false;
    }
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
        if (processName.equals(process.processName)) {

           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

the proccessName taken from this code, the pid is from android.os.Process.myPid():

```
private String getAppName(int pID)
```

{

```
String processName = "";
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
Iterator i = l.iterator();
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
while(i.hasNext()) 
{
      ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
      try 
      { 
          if(info.pid == pID)
          {
              CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
              //Log.d("Process", "Id: "+ info.pid +" ProcessName: "+ info.processName +"  Label: "+c.toString());
              //processName = c.toString();
              processName = info.processName;
          }
      }
      catch(Exception e) 
      {
            //Log.d("Process", "Error>> :"+ e.toString());
      }
 }
   return processName;
 }
```

hope you can tell whats wrong why I am getting always true on my first block of code.
thanks a lot!!

Comment: " it is possible if one app Laughed anther one " means what exactly? I'm pretty sure opening the app will just load an existing running one.

Comment: nope as I can see on runnig on os there are 2 apps that runs at once, the langher that runs the second and the original one

Comment: "it is possible if one app Laughed anther one and the user entering with a mobile to the second one, and will be 2 instance. " -- no, that is not possible. There will be at most one process for your application, unless you (mis)configured your application to behave otherwise. There may be more than one task associated with your application.

Comment: but how it can be that I can see the first app that starting the second is running and the second running that user runs it ,I updated me main question.

Comment: Are you talking about two completely different apps?

Comment: but the entry point changes upon context.the problem is when  starting the first one by the user I want to get  the corrent activity of the second app that aready langhted the first one

Comment: I think the right problem for that is :: App starts fresh from root activity instead of resuming background state -->that what I want